# The end of the string was reached with no closing bracket found: NodeJS & Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, express, pug

I am beginning my journey down the path of node (following the [rolling with mongo](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb) tutorial), and have written the following jade file

```
extends layout
block content
  h1= title
  form( method="post")
    div
      div
        span Title :
        input(type="text", name="title", id="editArticleTitle")
      div
        span Body :
        textarea(name="body", rows=20, id="editArticleBody)// <--- This line!
      div#editArticleSubmit
        input(type="submit", value="Send")
```

I get `The end of the string was reached with no closing bracket found.` coming out of the jade character parser.  It blames the line that is pointed to in the above code.  It's certainly possible that I'm missing a bracket, but I'm not seeing where it might be.

Here's the stack trace:

```
The end of the string was reached with no closing bracket found.
    at Function.parseMax (/home/me/Documents/node/blog/node_modules/jade/node_modules/character-parser/index.js:26:13)
    at Object.Lexer.bracketExpression (/home/me/Documents/node/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:138:33)
    at Object.Lexer.attrs (/home/me/Documents/node/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:524:24)
    at Object.Lexer.next (/home/me/Documents/node/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:788:15)
    at Object.Lexer.lookahead (/home/me/Documents/node/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:122:46)
    at Object.Parser.lookahead (/home/me/Documents/node/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:116:23)
    at Object.Parser.parseTag (/home/me/Documents/node/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:618:25)
    at Object.Parser.parseExpr (/home/me/Documents/node/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:199:21)
    at Object.Parser.block (/home/me/Documents/node/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:593:25)
    at Object.Parser.tag (/home/me/Documents/node/blog/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:722:26)
```

Comment: `textarea(name="body", rows=20, id="editArticleBody)` You're missing a closing double quote on the `id` attribute. `id="editArticleBody"`

Comment: ARG! I need to get some syntax highlighting.

Comment: What would be even cooler is if the error gave you a line number :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was late.  I was missing the closing quote

Comment: Mine was better. I was using Visual Studio Code, which apparently has a handy feature where it will occasionally clone a file you are working on in a very subtle manner so that you start working on the clone instead.